# c/c++ extension downloading for long time in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, symbolicc++

I am using the c++/c extension in vs code first time and after clicking on installing c/c++extension by microsoft and i cannot use this

```
**// Simple C++ program to display "Hello World" 
// Header file for input output functions 
#include<iostream> 
using namespace std; 
// main function - 
// where the execution of program begins 
int main() 
{ 
    // prints hello world 
    cout<<"Hello World"; 

    return 0; 
}**
```

[image: This looks a like]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to download the extension manually

1. Go to vscode cpp tools release page https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/releases
2. Scroll down and download the .vsix file corresponding to your OS (in your case it's win32)
   [look for your OS in a section like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lT29R.png)
3. Open command prompt and type in
   `code --install-extension <path to your downloaded .vsix file>`
4. Close and reopen VSCode and the extension downloading window should no longer appear